# Premature end of regular expression: /[^]+/

Tags: ruby, docker

I am trying to use the NLP tool [hyponymy extraction tool] to deal with some Japanese text files. by the way, I run it on a docker container.

- docker OS images: Ubuntu 18.04
- docker version: 18.06.0-ce
- ruby version: 1.8.7-p375
- rbenv version: 1.1.1-39-g59785f6

jcode.rb

```
11:def _regex_quote(str)
str.gsub(/(\\[\[\]\-\\])|\\(.)|([\[\]\\])/) do
  $1 || $2 || '\\' + $3
end
end
 private :_regex_quote
151:def delete!(del)
return nil if del == ""
self.gsub!(DeletePatternCache[del] ||= /[#{_regex_quote(del)}]+/, '')
end
```

del_mark.rb

```
103:REG_PAREN = /[#{Regexp.quote((PAREN.keys+PAREN.values).join(''))}]/
    REG_BPAREN = /^([#{Regexp.quote(PAREN.keys.join(''))}])/
    (main.opts).on('-p','--end-paren','先頭と末尾の括弧のみ取り除く'){|d|
      options[:pat] = Array.new if options[:pat] == FULL_SET
      options[:pat].push(REG_BPAREN)
    }
    (main.opts).on('-P','--only-paren','括弧のみ_に置き換え'){|d| 
      options[:pat] = Array.new if options[:pat] == FULL_SET
      PAREN_OUT= '_'
      options[:pat].push(REG_PAREN)
   }
   #(main.opts).on('-d','--date'){
   #options[:pat].push(REG_DATE)
   #}
  (main.opts).on('-r','--remove'){
    options[:remove]=true
  }

    main.option
130:(ARGV+[$stdin]).each{|file|
    fi = file
    if file != $stdin
      fi = open(file)
    end
    main.input = fi 
    #puts "F:#{file}";
   138: main.exec{|line|
      unless line 
        main.is_line_write = false
        next
      end
  163:line.each_char{|char|
  #puts "C:#{char}"
  165:options[:pat].each{|pat|
        if pat == REG_BOU || pat == REG_BPAREN
        elsif pat == REG_PAREN
          char =char.sub(REG_PAREN,PAREN_OUT)
        else 
          reg = check_reg(char,pat)
          if reg
       # line.delete
       173:line.delete!("#{char}")
      # line.delete!("#{char[0,1]}\s?")
      # line = line[0..nchar-1] + line[nchar+char.size..line.size-1]
      # line.delete!(Regexp.quote(char))
        line.gsub!(reg,'')
        flag = true
        break
      end
    end
```

Cut.rb

```
if @is_data_array
    cd = Array.new
    @column.each{|c|
      cd.push(data[c])
    }
    func.call(cd)
  else
158: @column.each{|c|
      #puts "LINE:#{c},#{data[c]}";
  160: ret = @negrect_pattern == nil || !(data[c] =~ @negrect_pattern ) ? func.call(data[c]) : negrect(data[c]){|d| func.call(d)} 
      unless ret # if ret is nil
        is_write = false
        next
      end
      data[c] = ret
    }
  endenter code here
```

After I start the tool, an error messages come out:

```
/root/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/lib/ruby/1.8/jcode.rb:153: warning: character class has `]' without escape
/root/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/lib/ruby/1.8/jcode.rb:153:in `delete!': premature end of regular expression: /[^]+/ (RegexpError)
from /ex-hyponymy-1.0/script/lib/del_mark.rb:173
from /ex-hyponymy-1.0/script/lib/del_mark.rb:165:in `each'
from /ex-hyponymy-1.0/script/lib/del_mark.rb:165
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/lib/ruby/1.8/jcode.rb:212:in `each_char'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/lib/ruby/1.8/jcode.rb:211:in `scan'
from /root/.rbenv/versions/1.8.7-p375/lib/ruby/1.8/jcode.rb:211:in `each_char'
from /ex-hyponymy-1.0/script/lib/del_mark.rb:163
from /ex-hyponymy-1.0/script/lib/Cut.rb:160:in `call'
from /ex-hyponymy-1.0/script/lib/Cut.rb:160:in `exec'
from /ex-hyponymy-1.0/script/lib/Cut.rb:158:in `each'
from /ex-hyponymy-1.0/script/lib/Cut.rb:158:in `exec'
from /ex-hyponymy-1.0/script/lib/del_mark.rb:138
from /ex-hyponymy-1.0/script/lib/del_mark.rb:130:in `each'
from /ex-hyponymy-1.0/script/lib/del_mark.rb:130
```

I do not understand the point. I wish someone can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `/[^]+/` as a regular expression: it's invalid.

The Ruby 1.8.x<sup>1</sup> regular expression engine treats `[` as the *start of a character class* and thinks that the `]` and `+` are characters *inside* the character class - a treated-as-literal-character `]` is allowed to follow a `^`-negation without escape<sup>1</sup>.

Thus the character class is not closed - and a "premature end" [of regular expression] error is raised.

The warning above that provides an *indicator*: "warning: character class has ]' *without* escape" indicating that the `]` did *not* close the character class, for the reason stated above.

<sup>1</sup> This is "old Ruby" rules. Ruby 2+ (maybe even 1.9+?) has *different* regex rules and raises a "empty char-class" error, which is less-magical and less confusing. Now might be a good time to update the Ruby version used..

---

Perhaps a character negation was not desired (`/[+^]/` or `/[\^]+/`)? Or perhaps there were meant to be other characters inside the character class (`/[^f]+/`)? Or perhaps it was mean to match any single character except a bracket and plus (`/[^]+]/`; or `/[^\]+]/` in Ruby 2+)? Or..

It really depends what the *actual* intent of the regular expression is.. just have to write it in a valid format.

Comment: As an additional possibility, in some languages, `/[^]/` is idiom for Ruby's `/./m` ("match every character except nothing" = "match every character, even newline"). E.g. JavaScript will accept it (even though there is `/./s` that matches Ruby's `/./m` semantics).

Comment: I think it was `/[\^]+/` in the end: OP seems to be using [this `jcode.rb`](https://github.com/agross/therightstuff.de/blob/93a61318c785ae6ed02c89d865812ee7ecd51642/tools/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/jcode.rb#L153), which uses its own `_regex_quote` function which presumably works well to quote regexps _when out of character class_, but does not do the right thing inside a character class, like in the linked line, where the quoting requirements are quite different.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks for your explanation, it really help me understand the problem. Sorry, I forgot to add the regular expression parts of jcode.rb and del_mark.rb source code,  now I added that, looks like the problem come from there.

Comment: @Amadan Thank you very much. I'm thinking about what  your said now.

Comment: @user2864740 Thank your help, follow your instructions, I fix the problem, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Amadan Thank your help, follow your instructions, I fix the problem, really appreciate it.